# Batch rename based on regex capture

Tags: regex, batch-rename

Forgive me my lack of research, but I'm just not familiar with all the tools out there.

I want to batch rename a list of files that goes like

```
some_name_n1_51000
some_name_n2_51000
some_name_n3_51000
...
```

that should actually be named

```
some_name_n51000_1
some_name_n51000_2
some_name_n51000_3
...
```

i.e. the 51000 and the serial number should swap position.

The following works on Debian, using the perl `rename` script (which is called `prename`):

```
prename -nv 's/some_name_n(\d{1,2})_51000/some_name_n51000_$1' *
```

Note that `-v` gives verbose output and `-n` means it does a dry run. The final `*` is a file selector.

Reasons why it didn't work at first:

- I used `rename` instead of the perl script `prename`.
- I forgot to capture the regex group between braces, which is then stored in the variable `$1` (`$2`, `$3` for the second and third group, and so on).

What can be improved:

- On Debian stretch this gives me a deprecation warning

  Deprecated program in use: rename as shipped with the Debian perl package 
  will be removed after the release of stretch. Please install the separate 
  'rename' package which will provide the same command.

The `rename` package, however, accepts slightly different commands.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have been struggling with `rename` trying to get it to rename based on regex capture, but I cannot find out how. The question is very clear, there is absolutely no basis for misunderstanding. From experience, people solve this using bash, awk, zmv or what have you, so providing what I already tried seemed unhelpful to me.

Someone familiar with the tools will probably solve this in 5 seconds, saving me tons of time and providing me with a template for future use. Plenty people love to spend that 5 seconds, like colleagues do all the time, but I guess for you this is about me groveling.

Comment: "I guess for you this is about me groveling" No it's not. It's about the community decided standards for question quality. If we just all answered every scripting question without regard to the effort shown by the asker the site would be overrun by gimethescriptz questions. Feel free to dispute the closure on https://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: In addition you don't even specify your operating system or scripting language. The question clearly does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: You are right, I overreacted.

Comment: I answered it, you can open it up if you want.

Comment: Ok. But please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.